# Generate Instagram ClientID and ClientSecret using a console app

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am designing a console app to extract some of our customers instagram feeds and save it in database. 
Everything else is ok but couldn't generate ClientId and ClientSecrect automatically to start with. Since it is auto app that picks up customer's user and password and extracts the instagram feeds of the user.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need your customers username and password? You cant do that...

You also cant just generate a ClientId and ClientSecret your self. To get your own client ID and client secret go to [Instagram](https://instagram.com/developer/register/) and register there for one. By clicking manage clients.

If you want to figure out how to get users feeds go to [Instagrams developer console](https://apigee.com/resources/instagram?apig_cc=1) and mess around in that.

Comment: Thanks Ril0n, I have generated my client id and secret but how can i pull my friend's public feed. Say I have 10 friends in instagram i need to pull all their public feed to store it in my database. I am having problem to pull their public feed.

Comment: as per the [instagram console](https://apigee.com/console/instagram)    users/{user-id}/media/recent  is how you would get to looking at the users feed. 

now to get the user ID you need to go through the relationships node using the users/{user-id}/followed-by and putting your own user-id in where it says {user-id}.

to get information about your self is just users/self

use the developer console to work out how you would do things and then go about trying to send and receive the data.